# Python Regex solution?

Tags: regex, python-3.x

I have a string:

```
line = "https://dbwebb.se/kunskap/uml#sequence, ftp://bth.com:32/files/im.jpeg, file://localhost:8585/zipit, http://v2-dbwebb.se/do%hack"
```

I want to get a result like this :

```
[('https', 'dbwebb.se', ''), ('ftp', 'bth.com', '32'), ('file', 'localhost', '8585'), ('http', 'v2-dbwebb.se', '')]
```

I tried like :

```
match = re.findall("([fh]t*ps?|file):[\\/]*(.*?)(:\d+|(?=[\\\/]))", line)
```

And than i got :

```
[["https", "dbwebb.se", ""], ["ftp", "bth.com", ":32"], ["file", "localhost", ":8585"], ["http", "v2-dbwebb.se", ""]]
```

There is one diffrence, you can se ":32" and ":8585". How can i do to get just "32" and "8585" and not the stupid ":" 
Thanx!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suggest

```
import re
line = line = "https://dbwebb.se/kunskap/uml#sequence, ftp://bth.com:32/files/im.jpeg, file://localhost:8585/zipit, http://v2-dbwebb.se/do%hack"
match = re.findall(r"([fh]t*ps?|file)://([^/]*?)(?::(\d+))?(?:/|$)", line)
print(match)
```

See the [Python demo](https://ideone.com/QA4di7)

The main point is `(?::(\d+))?(?:/|$` part where `:` and 1+ digits part is optional (`(?...)?` matches 1 or 0 times) and `(?:/|$)` matches a `/` or end of string.

**Details**

- `([fh]t*ps?|file)` - Group 1 (the first item in the tuple): a literal

  - `[fh]t*ps?` - `f` or `h`, zero or more `t`, `p` and 1 or 0 `s`s
  - `|` - or
  - `file` - `file` substring
- `://` - a literal substring
- `([^/]*?)` - Group 2 (the second item in the tuple): any 0 or more chars other than `/`
- `(?::(\d+))?` - an optional sequence of:

  - `:` - a colon
  - `(\d+)` - Group 2 (the third item in the tuple): one or more digits
- `(?:/|$)` - a `:` or end of string.

Answer (score 1):

Regex isn't the good tool to parse urls, there's a dedicated library to do this complicated task [urllib](https://docs.python.org/3/library/urllib.parse.html):

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

line = "https://dbwebb.se/kunskap/uml#sequence, ftp://bth.com:32/files/im.jpeg, file://localhost:8585/zipit, http://v2-dbwebb.se/do%hack"

result = []
for i in line.split(', '):
    o = urlparse(i)
    result.append([o.scheme, o.hostname, o.port])
```

Answer (score 1):

Instead of a regex, why not split on the `,` and then use Python's `urllib.parse.urlparse`, eg:

```
from urllib.parse import urlparse

line = "https://dbwebb.se/kunskap/uml#sequence, ftp://bth.com:32/files/im.jpeg, file://localhost:8585/zipit, http://v2-dbwebb.se/do%hack"
output = [urlparse(url) for url in line.split(', ')]
```

Gives you:

```
[ParseResult(scheme='https', netloc='dbwebb.se', path='/kunskap/uml', params='', query='', fragment='sequence'),
 ParseResult(scheme='ftp', netloc='bth.com:32', path='/files/im.jpeg', params='', query='', fragment=''),
 ParseResult(scheme='file', netloc='localhost:8585', path='/zipit', params='', query='', fragment=''),
 ParseResult(scheme='http', netloc='v2-dbwebb.se', path='/do%hack', params='', query='', fragment='')]
```

Then filter out the elements you want:

```
wanted = [(url.scheme, url.hostname, url.port or '') for url in output]
```

Which gives you:

```
[('https', 'dbwebb.se', ''),
 ('ftp', 'bth.com', 32),
 ('file', 'localhost', 8585),
 ('http', 'v2-dbwebb.se', '')]
```